# How can I get fixed order for all order by clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return a value indicating the row number of each result in the returned set.  i.e. I'd like the result to be as if I'd used the `row_number()` function with an `order by` window matching the statement's `order by` clause.

i.e.

```
select *
, row_number() over (order by /*order by columns*/) [row_number]
from someTable
order by /*the same columns in the same order as given above*/
```

However, I only want to change the `order by` clause; not the value in the window function.

Comment: This make absolutely no sense at all. You want the rows in a specific order regardless of the order. What are you trying to do?

Comment: what is the problem there actually?

Comment: well, the purpose is that i have a report that return some data and i want to add 1 more column that will always in that specific order however i order to know how many rows my query return

Comment: This problem does not make any sense to me at all.

Comment: You basically have *two* `ORDER BY` clauses here - **one** inside your call to the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` clause which defines the **order** of how those row numbers are calculated, and a **second**, independent `ORDER BY` that handles ordering the results of the `SELECT` query. So really, as long as you leave the `ORDER BY` inside the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` clause the same, the row numbers will always be based on the same ordering - no matter how the result of the `SELECT` is ordered - is that what you're looking for??

Comment: Yes that exactly what i need the row_number always the same however my select is ordered

Comment: It's all rather confusing and I suspect that you're after something which is the exact opposite of what many people are assuming here. Are you trying to create some form of `ROW_NUMBER()` expression that always returns the value `1` for the first result returned, `2` for the second, `3` for the third, *without* having to adjust any `ORDER BY` clause within the `ROW_NUMBER()` expression and just having it use the same ordering as the final `ORDER BY` clause causes?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's exactly what i need, a column that will always return 1 for first, 2 for second, 3 for third .........

Comment: (Of course, this would be far better if, say, you [edit] your question and show the result sets you expect to get for two different orderings)

Comment: Try creating actual tables of the results you expect from those queries and including those in your question as code. Just repeating "same order" **clearly** isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get row numbering without explicitly providing a column to order by within the `ORDER BY` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER` function.  Try this:

```
INSERT INTO @Table
    SELECT 1,'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'c' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'f' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10,'a'

SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) AS [Order] 
FROM 
    @Table 
ORDER BY 
    col1
```

**Update**

Another method that may prove to be more consistent is to add a dummy column and order by that for the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dummy) AS [Order] 
FROM 
    (select 0 dummy, * from @Table ) t
ORDER BY 
  col2
```

Comment: And now there is **no** guarantee on what row numbers will be assigned, which I don't think is the point here. And worse, it may *appear* to work on "toy" queries like this one.

Comment: Thank you, this is really what i need, i will try on my real data to see if there is any problem. And also this seem to only work on sql 2012 or higher, i try on sql 2008 and the result is different with same query

Comment: @SonNgo - as I tried to suggest in my comment, this may *appear* to work but is in no way guaranteed. `ORDER BY (select 1)` is effectively telling the system "all rows have the same ordering value. So assign row numbers in any order that is convenient". As soon as you encounter a significant amount of data or introduce complexity of any kind to the query, it's unlikely that the most convenient assignment strategy coincides with the final `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I don't make any guarantees as to whether this method will work for any given dataset.  Frankly, I'm surprised it works at all, even on "toy" queries.  But I've tried it on a number of queries of varying complexity, on largish tables (8.5 million rows), and have yet to have it not work.

Comment: Yes. Because programming by *coincidence* is the best way of writing software. If it was *documented* that window functions would fall back to result set ordering when their own `ORDER BY` clauses were inadequate then this would be a great answer (if it linked to such documentation). As it is, it *misleads* people at best.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, if the intent of this feature was to allow outside ordering to control the system, then `ORDER BY 1` or `ORDER BY *` would be natural candidates for allowing that to occur. You're *tricking* the compiler into accepting nonsense and, as such, no guarantees are offered when you do this.

Comment: Everyone can consider themselves appropriately warned.

Comment: if this is what OP wanted, the best option is actually to do it at the front end application !

Answer (score 0):

sure. This will do it

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS [Order] 
FROM   @Table 
ORDER BY [Order]
```

Comment: not really what i'm looking for. i want my select can order by anything but my [order] still stay the same

Comment: just change the ordering required in the `ROW_NUMBER()`. Isn't that the same ?

Comment: well, that should do it but i cant change the order in row_number () everytime i change order in my select, i need something to do it for me

Comment: why you can change the order in the select and can't change the row_number() ?

Comment: with this query, you don't have to change the ORDER BY clause, just change the row_number() !

Comment: what is your constraint ? consideration ? Why you can't do this, can't do that ?

Comment: Not really my point here, i just need a [order] column that will return 1 for first, 2 for second, 3 for third...... however the order in my select is

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this; though none are perfect:

**1)** Specify the order by in the row number's window, then order by the row number:

```
SELECT 
    *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) AS [Order]
FROM 
    @Table 
ORDER BY 
    [order]
```

i.e. this allows you to specify the `order by` values in one place, having both the `[order]` column and the order of the results match; but does it by specifying the order in a different part of the query.

This doesn't exactly match your requirements, but may be suitable (e.g. if your scenario is you don't want to risk your 2 order by clauses being incorrectly maintained / accidentally getting out of sync due to programmer error).

**2)** Specify the order programmatically.  This could be done from whatever code's calling your statement, or by using dynamic SQL.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
, @orderByStatement nvarchar(max)

set @orderByStatement = 'col2, col1'

set @sql = '
SELECT 
    *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @orderByStatement + ') AS [Order]
FROM 
    #Table --NB: would need to use a real or temp table rather than table variable to have this be visible to the dynamic SQL statement
ORDER BY ' + @orderByStatement 

exec (@sql)
```

This is useful if you're programmatically amending the order by clause and want to ensure that the window function adapts with it.
NB: you may need to add logic to handle the special case where no order by is given; either using a default order, or declaring & ordering by a fixed-value variable.

This could be used in conjunction with suggestion #1; only dynamically replacing the window's order-by clause, then ordering the results by that number.

**Summary / Question**

Which approach you choose depends on your requirements; i.e. why are you taking this approach?  My guess is you're working with a framework that allows you to setup a fixed query, only allowing you to amend the `ORDER BY` clause at runtime.  Sadly for that scenario neither of the above would work.  The accepted answer (i.e. ordering by a fixed value variable) will generally work (probably), but isn't guaranteed to; so may be acceptable depending on how important this value will be / the implications of what happens when this value is different to what's expected.